# put radio button for fingerprint in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to integrate radio buttons with a hand image for fingerprinting in `Bootstrap`? Is it possible to have an exact positioning for radio buttons to put just upper each finger and it stay unchanged for popular browsers (`IE, Firefox and Chrome`)? Indeed, I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this done you can use technique of element absolute positioning (radio-button) within parent element (image container).

```
/* 
  Set container position to relative
  Note: This will not affect parent's current position
*/

.image-container {
   position: relative;
}

/* 
   Now all children with position: absolute 
   would be position within their parent 
*/

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

For more details please take a look at the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZLRzy) I have created. It also includes transparent labels so clicking on the finger will actually select a radio button.

[image: fingerprint-demo]